# Как вывести данные из input route.panel на страницу?

Tags: api, яндекс-карты

Как вывести данные из input route.panel на страницу?[image: Вон оттуда, в любой input на странице]

Comment: Имеется ввиду из того инпута в любой другой на странице.

Answer (score 0):

Подпишитесь на изменение состояния панели [`IRotePanel.state`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/IRoutePanel-docpage/#field_detail__state) и доставайте оттуда `from` и `to`. Панель можно получить из контрола: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.RoutePanel-docpage/

Comment: А можно в виде кода, просто только начал знакомиться с данной технологией. Я просто не понимаю как вытащить его именно в свой input.

Comment: Не понятно как их вытаскивать, напишите кто-нибудь код. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @ЯрославЯкунин, зачем вам свой input, что вы пытаетесь сделать? Если вы хотите сделать свою панель, то вам надо использовать не контрол, а MultiRouter напрямую.